# Google BigQuery Analytic Functions - MAX(FUNCTION)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm trying to write a Query that will return the **maximum search volume** associated with a given **keyword** for its corresponding **url**.

The sample data set looks like:
[image]

The syntax I have so far is:

[image]

Ideally, the query would return the keyword with the highest search volume along with its url pair.

I'm not sure if I need to use an analytic function or if I can just create a self join? I've tried a variety of methods but not luck so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally, the query would return the keyword with the highest search volume along with its url pair.

It *looks* like you just want `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by search_vol desc limit 1
```

This gives you the row with the greatest `search_vol` within the whole table.

On the other hand, if you want the most searched keyword *per url*, then it is a greatest-n-per-group problem. Here is a solution in the spirit of your original attempt, using an analytic function:

```
select t.* except (rn)
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by url order by search_vol desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

`rank()` allows top ties, if any. If you want to avoid that, use `row_number()`.

Comment: To mimic a MAX result RANK should be used instead of ROW_NUMBER

Comment: @dnoeth: yes that's a good point. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY search_vol DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY url
```